# gender classification of blog authors

Tags: nlp, weka, text-classification

I am working on gender classification of blog authors.I am using Weka for classification. The classifiers are SVM and Naive Bayesian classifier, but my accuracy is between 50% to 60% and
now am doubt about my feature set. The features I am using are POStags, words ending with ale,ably etc.,blog words, stemming etc..
I am referencing this paper

[Paper Link](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D10-1021/)

Does anyone have any ideas what a better feature set would be?

Comment: You might want to post the URL of the paper you're referring to.

Comment: http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.aclweb.org%2Fanthology%2FD10-1021&ei=SSDcUti6JIPwiQfXmoCQCA&usg=AFQjCNEhGNYlolqTyGP7aYc4KNaAmnIy0Q&bvm=bv.59568121,d.dGI

Comment: You might want to edit the question to put that into the post.

Answer (score 1):

As an open research question, I strongly recommend you to check the feature sets used in the "[evaluation labs on uncovering plagiarism, authorship, and social software misuse](http://pan.webis.de/)", the PAN series, which feature datasets and many papers on the topic of Author Profiling: age and gender.

You can find [the datasets used in 2013 runs](http://www.uni-weimar.de/medien/webis/research/events/pan-13/pan13-web/author-profiling.html), and the [descriptions of the approaches used by several research groups](http://www.uni-weimar.de/medien/webis/research/events/pan-13/pan13-web/about.html#proceedings).

Answer (score 0):

Having worked on the same problem quite a while ago, I could conform to the conclusion that it's a bit tiresome reproducing the results of the paper. The 20,000 (approx.) POS sequences obtained through their variable length POS mining algorithm is rather untidy, and a major factor behind the irreproducibility. Also, given the size of their dataset (~3,000 blog posts), an accuracy of 88% sounds pretty counter-intuitive.

Maybe, some larger corpora (for instance, the Blog authorship corpus) could help to shed light on the generalization capability of the features.

Comment: how was your experience with Blog authorship corpus. How did you approach this problem.